# What does this sentence means?

Tags: meaning

"This person—a gray-headed man, of quiet and most
respectful deportment—found it necessary to explain that his
master still remained in his study, or private apartment; on
entering which, an hour before, he had expressed a wish on
no account to be disturbed."

"on entering which, an hour before, he had expressed a wish on
no account to be disturbed." This part seems confusing to me? Can you parse it

Comment: If you are quoting something, please please please include a link to the source in your question. Not only does it allow us to look at the quote at the place you found it, but it helps us look at surrounding context.

Comment: @HUN In addition to including a link to Hawthorne's work, as Alan says, you should tell us what it is that confuses you. Is there a word or phrase that you don't understand? You probably do know what _he had expressed a wish_ means; tell us what you _don't_ understand.

Comment: I get confused with "on entering which", what's another way to say this.

Comment: See the answer below: the referent of _which_ is _apartment_ in the previous clause. Read the clause as: _on entering the apartment, he had expressed..._  (Do you know how to add a link to the source in your question?)

Comment: "Jimmy Crack Corn, and I don't care, My master's gone away."

Answer (score 0):

"On entering *which* [the apartment] an hour before, *he* [the master]  had expressed a wish [that he should] *on no account to* [under no circumstances] be disturbed."

Thus reworked, the sentence reads, "On entering the apartment an hour before, the master had expressed a wish that he should under no circumstances be disturbed."

Comment: account in this case means explanation or description?

Comment: @HUN: "On no account" in this context, means "under no circumstances.